# When I want to look at the "newest folder" I need to scroll down the list using Windows XP/Vista/7. Is there a solution to this?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista

Let's say I have 100 files and 100 folders in a folder "my stuff".

More often than not, I need to access the "newest folder" -- that's probably the case, because usually, people need their most recent stuff -- that's also called the principle of locality or maybe proximity.

But, when I sort the files / folder by "Date modified", it is always some where in the middle that the newest folder is on the list.  I need to scroll and visually locate the folder.

It happens all the time.  I think the reason is, the files are sorted by "newest files first, and then newest folders", or by "oldest folder first and oldest files".  (you can toggle it by clicking on "Date Modified" bar in the folder window).

So no matter how you choose it, the newest folder IS ALWAYS SOMEWHERE IN THE MIDDLE.

Won't it actually make sense to sort it by

1. Newest Files First, and then Newest Folders First
2. Oldest Files First, and then Oldest Folders First (after the toggle)

then in the second case, we can easily get to the newest folder by going to the other end of the list.

Any method to make it work better given Windows likes to sort it this way?

It makes me wonder, do the designers at Microsoft not need to get to the newest folder, so they don't take this into consideration?

Comment: Voila! End of discussion, now all pretend to be friends, thnx bye

Comment: @Ivo - It was especially made for you to enjoy moderation powers ;) Joke aside, thank you, such things and mood have nothing to do on SU.

Comment: Have you tried grouping by type? Right-click on an empty space in the folder window, select _Group By > Type_. After this, the sorting choice you apply will only apply within a group - such as the _File folder_ group. You can also do _View > Collapse all groups_ and then expand the _File folder_ group to just see the folders. As an added bonus, you can also group by date modified or date created, which will put both files **and** folders modified in the same time-span under the same group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, Windows Explorer can't even sort the directories correctly on modification date!

All I can suggest is to use an alternative Explorer.

My own favorite is the free [Servant Salamander 1.52](http://www.altap.cz/download.html#salrel), which I guarantee sorts correctly the directories, but you can also pick one from the following 25 alternatives:

[15 Windows Explorer alternatives compared and reviewed](http://www.simplehelp.net/2006/10/11/10-windows-explorer-alternatives-compared-and-reviewed/)
[10 (more) Windows Explorer alternatives compared and reviewed](http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/07/19/10-more-windows-explorer-alternatives-compared-and-reviewed/)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried sorting on date created, not modified?

That would give you access to the most recently created files, not files that constantly change (like a database)

Comment: no, no matter it is "Date Created" or "Date Modified", it is the same result -- the newest folders are some where in the middle of the long list.

However, on Win 7, if you sort by "Date", then if you click on this "Date" heading, then the newest folders do show up at the top of the list.  If it doesn't click it again and it will.  Why the difference between "Date" and "Date created" or "Modified"...